raspberry pi pico "assertion "tud_inited()""
I'm sometimes getting the following error (printed over serial)
assertion "tud_inited()" failed: file "<...>/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c"t

then the pico dies.
I'm using the c/c++ sdk and the tinyusb stack. I've looked into the corresponding file but couldn't really make a picture of what's going on. It seems like the assertion message got cut off, so I have even less to go with.
I'm not asking where the issue in my code is, but I would rather like to know what this assertion asserts and when it's supposed to fail (so that I can fix the issue myself).
I can't even pinpoint the issue in the code. In one build it's fine and on another it dies (doing some refactoring right now, so I might be initializing something before something else that I shouldn't)
Edit 1:
Running the following code already make the error appear.
int main() {
    // tusb_init();
    stdio_init_all();

    puts("v=============================================v");
    puts("v================= STARTUP ===================v");
    puts("v=============================================v");
    return 0;


Note: Is there a better place to ask this question?

Well... The error gives you the source file to check. Looking at sdk in src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c you find the assert() in a preprocessor conditional, e.g. #if !defined(LIB_TINYUSB_DEVICE) ... #else assert(tud_inited()); // we expect the caller to have initialized if they are using TinyUSB So it looks very much like you have defined LIB_TINYUSB_DEVICE for the tinyusb stack, but haven't initialized it. I haven't used the tinyusb feature of the sdk before, but the failed assertion is clear. The SDK has undergone large updates recently -- is yours up to date?

@DavidC.Rankin I've seen that as well, and tried to init it, tusb_init I would assume?? Didn't help. It's maybe a month old or so, but I can try to update it later

I'd go back to your git clone of the SDK and change into the directory and do git pull && git submodule update --init to make sure you have the new ver. 2.0 SDK. Thousands of changes.
